# How to unroll a row in Excel, to have a better view for editing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, database, microsoft-access, spreadsheet

Let's say we have an Excel spreadsheet like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way, ideally built-in in Excel, to **"unroll a row"** to be able to:

- have a better view of all the data in this row
- have an easier editing of all the columns of this row

?

Example: clicking on the left blue button of the row #3 (Jane Smith), would temporarily give something like:

[image]

allowing a better view and an easier editing. Clicking on the `CLOSE` button would go back to the normal spreadsheet view.

If I remember correctly, I think this is possible out-of-the-bow in database programs like MS Access, but how to do it with Excel?

Comment: You can format cells to wrap text. The row expands to display all the text. Home menu, Cells group on ribbon, Format button, Format Cells... in pull down menu, Alignment tab in dialog, check the Wrap text box. If you want to automate as you are suggesting, use the macro recorder to identify which objects/methods/properties are involved in switching   the text wrapping format on and off, then armed was this knowledge write your own Vba and, if necessary, amend your question to show what you have tried.

Comment: @DMM Thanks but I want to avoid the `Wrap text` feature (I already used it in the past). I would like to keep the "spreadsheet view" with a small row-height for all rows (like in my first screenshot), to see the big picture. Then I'd like to have an "editing view" like in my second screenshot.

Comment: A user form is possibly the way to go. This page (https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/excel-tutorial/userform-in-excel) takes you through the basic ideas. The form is used to display a row of data at a time, in a format you design, and allows it to be editted and updated. Whilst the page is mainly concerned with using a form to create rows of data, if you can understand the principles involved you will be able to adapt the approach  to allow you to choose a row and then display and edit within the form.

Comment: It might be worth a note:  "Wrap text" doesn't work om merged cells.

Comment: That seems to be an answer @DMM Why not convert the information you provided in your comment to an answer and get reputation points from it?

Comment: Good idea @ChrisRogers. If someone has a working method, I just started a bounty.

Comment: @Chris, to get the "canonical answer" the OP seeks really requires a better specification of the problem. I would hazard a guess the requirement is that the Name and UserId field would be non-editable whilst fields Note1,...,Note 4 would be editable and that the user form would be used solely for editing and not creating or deleting records. But, of course, I could be wrong. In any case, this isn't a free code-writing service (bounty notwithstanding). I have made a suggestion, others can pursue if they wish.

Comment: @DMM There could also be useful lesser known solutions (other than with custom code), that's why I started the bounty. The current answer is 99% of what I'm looking for, I hope the two little drawbacks of this solution can be solved (see my comment in the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers have used Excel's built-in [Data Form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-edit-find-and-delete-rows-by-using-a-data-form-17bca0a4-3ba5-444a-983c-a8ce70609374). This provides a powerful mechanism for adding/editing/deleting rows of data in a data list without any need for VBA. A data form has the following features

- It defaults to the first data row when activated from the ribbon/quick access toolbar, though allows intuitive navigation to subsequent rows
- All fields (columns) in the data list are editable and a separate one line textbox is provided for changing each field

In some circumstances, these features may be less than ideal - for example when data items comprise very lengthy text strings.

As an alternative to a Data Form, the solution below uses a [UserForm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/controls-dialogboxes-forms/create-a-user-form). A userform provides greater flexibility than a data form but has the downside that VBA coding and some design skills are required. The userform shown is based on the following assumptions about the OP's requirements

1. The major requirement of the userform is to view and change the content in columns *Note1*, *Note2*, *Note2* and *Note4* of the data list
2. The *Name* and *UserId* columns are simply used to identify the data row. The values within these two columns are correct and will not need changing
3. There is no requirement for the userform to provide the capability for adding or deleting rows of the data list
4. There should be the flexibility to move between rows of the data list
5. The userform should be capable of being switched on and off

The userform is shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Data list showing userform overlaid]

### Behaviour of the userform

1. When the worksheet is in "form mode" (see 4., below), selecting a **single** cell within any of the columns headed *Note1*, *Note2*, *Note3* or *Note4* displays the content of the corresponding *Note* item, along with the *Name* and *UserId* values from the start of the row. The *Note* involved (*Note1*, *Note2*, *Note3* or *Note4*) is indicated by the label to the left of the large textbox in the userform. The userform is modal, so the user must interact with the form to progress.
2. The text in the large *Note* textbox may be changed by the user. The button labelled "Save Changes" writes the current content of the textbox to the corresponding *Note* cell of the worksheet and "closes" the userform (removes it from the display). The button labelled "Cancel" also "closes" the userform, though without updating the corresponding *Note* cell.
3. No navigation functionality is provided in the userform. Instead, the user "closes" the form (using either of the two buttons) and can navigate using the standard Excel interface to other cells. The form reappears whenever the current selected cell(s) on the worksheet meet the condition specified in 1., above.
4. The worksheet remains in "form mode" until the userform is closed with the "Close" button (the standard "X" at the top-right of the form). The worksheet can be put back into "form mode" by running the macro `FormMode`.

### Structure and Organisation

1. The data, including the header row and the *Name* and *UserId* columns are contained in a named range called `MyData`
2. The userform is called `EditForm`. The form contains 5 labels, 1 textbox, 2 buttons and the standard "Close button" on the title bar. `EditForm` has a boolean property `EditOn` which determines whether "form mode" is on or off.
3. There is a VBA module which declares a couple of `Public` variables `intDataRow` and `intDataColumn` which are the row and column containing the cell within `MyData` that provides the contents of the *Note* textbox displayed in `EditForm`. The module also contains the macro `FormMode` which simply switches "form mode" on by the assignment `EditForm.EditOn = True`.
4. The worksheet containing `MyData` contains a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` procedure.  This procedure tests

   - whether "form mode" is on
   - whether a single cell has been selected on the worksheet
   - whether this cell is contained within a *Note* column in `MyData` (after the header row)
     If any test fails, the procedure does nothing. Otherwise it calculates the `intDataRow` and `intDataColumn` values of the selected cell and causes `EditForm` to be displayed through its `Show` method.
5. The module for EditForm contains the following procedures:

   - `Property Let` and `Property Get` for the `EditOn` property of the userform
   - `UserForm_Activate` event procedure. The event is triggered by `EditForm.Show` (in 4., above) and populates the userform from the worksheet based on the current values of `intDataRow` and `intDataColumn`.
   - button `_Click` procedures for the "Save Changes" and "Cancel" buttons. The former updates `Range("MyData").Cell(intDataRow,intDataColumn)` with the contents of the userform's textbox. Both procedures remove the userform from the display ("close" it) through the form's `Hide` method.

A screenshot of the VBA project is shown below.

[image: VBA Project]

The form is basic but functional. It can obviously be adapted and improved to meet requirements. It provides a different model to that provided by Excel's Data Form.

The VBA code utilised is listed below.

**CODE FOR WORKSHEET CONTAINING RANGE MyData**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not EditForm.EditOn Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
  
    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Or _
        Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
  
  
    If Target.Row < Range("MyData").Row + 1 Or _
        Target.Row > Range("MyData").Row + Range("MyData").Rows.Count - 1 Or _
        Target.Column < Range("MyData").Column + 2 Or _
        Target.Column > Range("MyData").Column + Range("MyData").Columns.Count - 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    intDataRow = 1 + Target.Row - Range("MyData").Row
    intDataColumn = 1 + Target.Column - Range("MyData").Column
       
    EditForm.Show
        
End Sub
```

**CODE FOR FORM EditForm**

```
Option Explicit

Private pEditMode As Boolean

Public Property Let EditOn(bValue As Boolean)
    pEditMode = bValue
End Property

Public Property Get EditOn() As Boolean    
    EditOn = pEditMode
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Name_Field.Caption = Range("MyData").Cells(intDataRow, 1)
    UserID_Field.Caption = Range("MyData").Cells(intDataRow, 2)
    NoteLabel.Caption = "Note" & (intDataColumn - 2) & ":"
    Note_Field.Value = Range("MyData").Cells(intDataRow, intDataColumn)
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub
    
Private Sub SaveButton_Click()
    Range("MyData").Cells(intDataRow, intDataColumn) = Note_Field.Value
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

**CODE FOR MODULE**

```
Option Explicit

Public intDataRow As Integer
Public intDataColumn As Integer

Sub FormMode()
    EditForm.EditOn = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to add a VBA macro that will show a
[Data Form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-edit-find-and-delete-rows-by-using-a-data-form-17bca0a4-3ba5-444a-983c-a8ce70609)
for the current row.

- In Excel
  [Show the Developer tab](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd)
- Save the workbook as a macro-enabled `.xlsm` file (not `.xlsx`)
- Go to the Developer tab
- Click Visual Basic
- Select the Menu entry of *Insert > Module*
- In the text-editor that opens, copy the following text:

  ```
    Option Explicit
    Sub CurrRowForm()
    SendKeys "{DOWN " & ActiveCell.Row - 2 & "}{TAB 3}"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
  ```
- Save by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
  and leave the VBA editor by
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
- To test the new macro:

  - Select your row
  - In the Developer tab click Macros
  - Ensure the `CurrRowForm` macro is selected
  - Click the Run button
  - The result should look like this when the second row is the current:

    [image]

You may assign the macro a hotkey by :

- Enter *Developer > Macros*
- Ensure the macro `CurrRowForm` is selected
- Click Options
- Select your Shortcut key
- Click OK

[image]

You may also for `CurrRowForm`
[Add a macro button to the ribbon](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read any comments mentioning the built in Excel data form on the Data tab, `Data Entry` group. <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> keys in Windows.

Formulas are read only, cell protection is maintained; however, there's no ability to change heights or widths of fields.

Fields will widen automatically but only to a point. You could set up a hotkey to avoid the Ribbon key sequence.

Comment: Really great @bugdrown! Two little drawbacks (but there's maybe a workaround?): 1) it would be great to have a wider form width by default   2) is it possible to launch this form directly at row number 100? In my tests, the form is always launched at the first row.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know if you can control which record the form starts with.

Comment: Is there a way to associate a keyboard shortcut to "Start this data entry form at the cursor's current row" @bugdrown?

Comment: I've only poked around a little but couldn't find any VBA actions other than `.ShowDataForm` and I don't know if you can set up a hotkey for direct record access. However, there is a `Criteria` button that would allow you to search any of the rows in the list. If you set up a column that has the row number (e.g., `=ROW()`) then you could click on the criteria button and go to a specific record.

Comment: 30+ years of excel and I'm still learning new things (or relearning something I forgot was there). Here's the [link for more detail](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-edit-find-and-delete-rows-by-using-a-data-form-17bca0a4-3ba5-444a-983c-a8ce70609374). A caveat about using `=ROW()` is that if you delete any rows, rows beyond that get renumbered, so you can't apply meaning beyond a quicker navigation method.

Comment: @harrymc answers shows using VBA and a customized form. More form information [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-forms-form-controls-and-activex-controls-on-a-worksheet-15ba7e28-8d7f-42ab-9470-ffb9ab94e7c2) or any web search would probably reveal.

Comment: @gns100 `ROW()` was only intended to be a navigation method for the OP. Deleting a row won't change the utility of this approach.