# One-click solution to expand a row to full height (that shows all the data)

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, spreadsheet

Is there a one-click or keyboard-shortcut solution to enable/disable *"Wrap text"*  to **all cells of the current row**?

[image]

This would allow a better edition of the current row, and being able to do this in one-click / one keyboard shortcut would be very handy, instead of having to:

- manually select the current row
- go to "Home" Ribbon, click `Wrap Text...`
- unselect the row
- go back to the previous current cell
- go back to the previous Ribbon tab

Here is a linked topic [How to unroll a row in Excel, to have a better view for editing?](https://superuser.com/questions/1695332/how-to-unroll-a-row-in-excel-to-have-a-better-view-for-editing), but here it's discussed with a separate Data entry form.

Answer (score 1):

This requires VBA and using the following macro:

```
Sub vba_wrap_text()
  Rows(ActiveCell.Row).WrapText = True
End Sub
```

The worksheet needs to be saved as `.xlsm` for macros to be enabled.
The macro can be used from the Developer pane, or even
added as a button to the ribbon.

You will find a detailed description of how to add a macro to the workbook in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1695892/8672)
of mine (from the same post whose link you already mentioned).

For assigning a shortcut to the macro see:
[2 Ways to Assign Keyboard Shortcuts to Macros](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/keyboard-shortcut-run-macro/).

For global use of the macro see:

- [Can You Permanently Save a Macro in Excel for Use in All Workbooks](https://www.pryor.com/blog/save-your-excel-macro-for-use-in-all-workbooks/)
- [How To Create A Macro-Enabled Template In Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2406-excel-template-macro-enabled.html)

Comment: Thanks @harrymc! Is here a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to such a macro (like the TAB key), and that this macro is available in all past and future Excel projects? (without having to rename them to `.xlsm` one by one, and add this macro to all of them manually)? Is there a concept of "general purpose" macro that is available for all spreadsheets?

Comment: I added the information into my answer. However, the default Excel Workbook file format (`.xlsx`) does not support macros.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to save both your code and also the keyboard-shortcut-binding in `personal.xlsb` ? Here it's about a recorded-macro https://www.pryor.com/blog/save-your-excel-macro-for-use-in-all-workbooks/, do you think we call put your code + shortcut in this `personal.xlsb`?

Comment: I gave above this link, and the method can be used for any macro, recorded or not.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of AutoHotkey tests, here is a first solution:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe excel.exe
    Tab:: SendInput {Alt}LQ
#ifWinActive
```

(for Excel FR version; it's probably different for the ENG version)

It doesn't apply *"Wrap text..."* to all cells of the row, but only the current cell, it's already a beginning.

Since I generally don't use <kbd>TAB</kbd> in Excel, I can use this keyboard shortcut.

[Example screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xueu.jpg).

Comment: TAB is one of the most useful keys on the keyboard; use it to loop through GUI elements (SHIFT+TAB for backwards), jump from one input field to next, jump from one button to next - press button using SPACE-key or ENTER. Add the use of cursor keys and you may handle much software from the keyboard only - much faster than grabbing the mouse. A person sitting right beside you will not understand what you're doing,

Comment: Yeah @Hannu I use TAB all the time in many programs (text editor etc.), but in the precise case of Excel, I rarely use it, and I mostly use arrow keys. Of course we can adapt this solution here with another key.