# Table Data Entry Form would pop-up when the user clicked the button

Tags: microsoft-excel

I’ve a worksheet containing a Table. I’ve added the
Form command to the QAT and when I select a cell in
the Table and then press the Form icon in the QAT,
the data entry form pops up – as expected.

I can’t expect my end-users to know about an icon on
the QAT!

I would like to put a button on the worksheet
(Developer -> Inset - sort of thing, don’t really
care if it’s a Form Controls or an ActiveX Controls).

The Data Entry Form would pop-up when the user
clicked the button.

From the button’s VBA _Click() method, I’ve been able
to select the table;

`ActiveSheet.ListObjects(“Table1”).Range.Select`

But I don’t know how to make the Data Entry Form
pop-up.

Any help would be appreciated (I’ve tried a web
search but to no avail – can’t believe I’m the
only person to come across this requirement).

Comment: See if the answer to this question helps: https://superuser.com/questions/1695332/how-to-unroll-a-row-in-excel-to-have-a-better-view-for-editing#1695791

Answer (score 0):

After more web searches I found the reason why ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm,
which I had already tried, did not work. The table either has to start
in cell A1 or have the name “database”.

The following code works as required;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Name = "database"

ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm

End Sub
```